# What's causing my flexbox container to not scroll horizontally despite using overflow-x: scroll?

Tags: html, css

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here and this was supposed to work. I'm not able to set the desired width for the child elements and make the parent overflow with a horizontal scroll. After a specific width the width won't increase and seems to get stuck at that point.

This is the html -

```html
 <div className="container">
        <div className="item">item 1</div>
        <div className="item">item 2</div>
        <div className="item">item 2</div>
 </div>
```

And the css -

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.item {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 25rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-darkness-yx1wht

Comment: The fact that you did nothing to prevent your flex items from being allowed to shrink below the specified width.

Comment: @CBroe sorry I don't understand. I have set width for the child elements?

Comment: flex items with a simple width specified, are allowed to grow or shrink by default, if you want a different behavior, you need to explicitly specify it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions to this is adding `min-width` instead of just `width` and if you need it in responsive to change you can continue manipulating with `min-width`

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-cache-ekok4i)

Comment: wow this is working! But I don't understand why? It doesn't consider width but considers min-width ?

Comment: Another solution to it is adding `width: fit-content;` in .container class and you wont need min-width at all. I have already updated the link you can check the changes. If you found it helpful mark it as answered!

Comment: In my original use case the container was supposed to be fixed width. But I still don't understand why min-width works..

Comment: Thanks for this solution - min-width works along with a fixed-width on the parent